# Count number of nodes within given range in AVL tree

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, avl-tree

Suppose I have an AVL tree of *distinct* integers. I need to determine the number of nodes which lie in the interval [a, b) where a < b. Note that [a, b) is supplied by the user and hence I do not know beforehand what the value of a and b are. Also, a and b may not be present in the tree at all. For example, if I have a tree containing the integers {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7} then the user should expect an answer of 3 if he supplies the interval [3, 7).

A naive implementation would be to traverse every node and increment the count by 1 every time a node is found in the given interval. But this would have a worst case time complexity of O(n), as it is possible for every single integer in the tree to be within the given range. I need a faster algorithm, and after doing some research I found that it requires storing a size statistic in every node so that the rank of any given node can be easily computed.

I would like to do something like rank(b) - rank(a), but the problem is that a and b may not exist in the tree. In the above example, rank(7) would return 6 but rank(3) will not return any meaningful value.

Can anyone offer suggestions as to how I can address this issue? Also, I know that there is another similar question on this website, but that one involves C++ while this one involves Java. Also, I could not find a satisfactory answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented a stack based tree iterator for an AVL tree some (long) time ago. It should work for your case like this:

- create an array "treestack" which holds structs for traversal info. The struct just needs a bool "visited", and a pointer to your node type. The array can be of static size e.g. hold 64 info elements (one for each level of your tree, so this 64 will mean your tree contains max 4G nodes)
- change the search method of your AVL tree to put the root node at treestack[0] when you begin with the search, and put all other nodes on top of the treestack as you follow the left and right child nodes during your search. Edit: Note that an unsuccessful search will result in your treestack having a node with the next smaller or next higher value, which is exactly what you want (just skip counting in case it's smaller, we still have abvalid iterator start oath).

You've now a path un your treestack which you can use for subsequent in-order traversal to find the next higher values. In-order traversal using the stack works like this:

- start at the last element in treestack, keep a treeindex which is initially = arrayindex of the last item.
- When there is a right node, and it is not marked visited: try follow ONE right of the current node, then ENDLESS to the left of any following nodes. Wherever you stop (so also if there are no left nodes but a single right one) is the next higher value. Put all nodes at the end of your tree stack as you follow them and inc your treeindex as you follow paths. And Mark the choosen final node with the next higher value as visited. Increase your node counter+1.
- now to find subsequent higher values, ascend in the tree by taking treeindex-1 in your treestack as current node, an repeat the above step to find the next node with higher value.
- if there is no right child node the current node, and the node is not marked visited: mark as visited, and inc node counter by 1
- you're done when you either reach the root node with treeindex 0 or your node containing max value.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
rank(b) - rank(a)
```

what I would do is

```
rank(X) - rank(Y)
```

X is the very first node having value > b.

Y is the very first node having value >= a.

Comment: How do I find the very first node having value > v, or conversely, value < v, where v is an arbitrary value? That's the part I'm really struggling with. It's a simple idea but I'm having much difficulty trying to implement it, due to the number of cases involved.